# Building an awesome 3.5 config for two-step actions

Tags: lua, keyboard-shortcuts, awesome-wm

Not sure exactly how to phrase this, but I'm trying to construct a lua method to be able to have two key commands for an action

say `meta-r,4` Where I'd push meta and <kbd>R</kbd> and then release both keys and push <kbd>4</kbd>, and it would say, put a client on monitor <kbd>4</kbd>, or something like that.

I haven't been able to find good google references for something like this, and looking at the awesome APIs I'm not seeing anything either.

EDIT: an example is how you change windows in screen, one pushes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>4</kbd> to go to the 4th window.

Comment: I think you meant `meta and r` instead of `meta and 4`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, and added a more concrete example.

Comment: These are called modal keybindings. Look at [this documentation](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Modal_Keybindings) to create a mode.

Comment: AHA! That's it, if you stick that in an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called modal key-bindings. Look at [this documentation](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Modal_Keybindings) to create a mode.